# How to install/locate R.h and Rmath.h header files?

Tags: r, header-files

I am trying to compile some C code (called rand_beta) in terminal which contains the lines to include R.h and Rmath.h header files using `gcc -o rand_beta rand_beta.c` so I can then call the code from within R.
However, I get the error messages:

```
rand_beta.c:1:15: error: R.h: No such file or directory
rand_beta.c:2:19: error: Rmath.h: No such file or directory
```

It seems that these header files which should come installed with R are not on my system.

Can someone guide me as to how I can get my computer to find the R header files? Do I need to download them from somewhere?

Comment: What operating system are you on? How did you install R?

Comment: Headers are source files. Almost all installers do not "install" the source code; they just install the built binaries.

Comment: Removing rcpp tag as this has nothing whatsoever to do with the Rcpp package.

Answer (score 15):

The other answers try to guess where your R installation directory is. But there is a more robust solution. Use the `R.home` command in **`R`** to find it wherever it is:

```
> R.home('include')
/usr/lib64/R/include
```

That is the folder containing `R.h` and `Rmath.h` on my system. Your folder may be in a different place.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it is not system dependent and can also be used for `lib` R directory with `R.home("lib")`.

Answer (score 9):

You first need to locate those headers. In my system, they are located in `/usr/lib64/R/include/R.h`, part of the `R-devel` package I installed with `yum`.

Then use the `-I` option of `gcc` to tell `gcc` where to find them.

```
gcc -I/usr/lib64/R/include  -o rand_beta rand_beta.c
```

Then, you will also most probably need to export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to run your compiled program:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/R/lib ./rand_beta
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, actually I guess I just needed to use R CMD SHLIB rand_beta.c instead, as this creates the .so file which I need for R.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to specify some environment variables to directly use the include path:

```
export CPATH=/usr/lib64/R/include/
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/lib64/R/include/
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/lib64/R/include/
export GCC_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/lib64/R/include/
```

This should then run fine:

```
gcc -o rand_beta rand_beta.c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo yum install R-devel
```

as error suggests helped me