# make install not working with R4.0.2 in conda env

Tags: r, installation, makefile, conda

I have a conda env with R4.0.2. When I tried to install R package zip I had problems with C compilation.

At first installation was failing as it could not find R.h. I had set C paths for R.h as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33573979, e.g. `export CPATH=/home/kh/miniconda3/envs/rpy2_3/lib/R/include/`  where the path leads to dir with R.h. However, I then got the below error. It seems that make install is not working properly. Any suggestions?

```
-o zip init.o miniz.o rzip.o zip.o unixutils.o
/bin/sh: line 2: -o: command not found
make: *** [/home/kh/miniconda3/envs/rpy2_3/lib/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: zip] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'zip'
* removing '/home/kh/miniconda3/envs/rpy2_3/lib/R/library/zip'
```

---

EDIT:

`conda install r-zip (from within evn)` does not work properly - I have R4.0.2 and conda installs zip from earlier version:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'zip':
 package 'zip' was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
```

regarding my shlib.mk, this are the contents. I will try to set the variables OBJECTS and SHLIB_LINK

```
cat /home/kh/miniconda3/envs/rpy2_3/lib/R/share/make/shlib.mk
## ${R_HOME}/share/make/shlib.mk

all: $(SHLIB)

$(SHLIB): $(OBJECTS)
    @if test  "z$(OBJECTS)" != "z"; then \
      echo $(SHLIB_LINK) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(ALL_LIBS); \
      $(SHLIB_LINK) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(ALL_LIBS); \
    fi

.PHONY: all shlib-clean

shlib-clean:
    @rm -Rf .libs _libs
    @rm -f $(OBJECTS) symbols.rds


## FIXME: why not Rscript?
symbols.rds: $(OBJECTS)
    @$(ECHO) "tools:::.shlib_objects_symbol_tables()" | \
      $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --no-echo --args $(OBJECTS)
```

---

EDIT
What at the end worked was copying Makeconf file from freshly made env (as suggested before) and editing the paths to point to the correct env. I also reset the variables from above, but I am not sure if this was in fact needed.

Comment: Find the command in the makefile `/home/kh/miniconda3/envs/rpy2_3/lib/R/share/make/shlib.mk` line 6 and you'll see that recipe uses some variable as the command to invoke, and that variable is empty.  Most likely it seems like it should contain the name of your `zip` utility.

Comment: Why is it compiling at all? `conda install -n rpy2_3 r-zip` should simply work. One should not use `install.packages` in Conda R environments.

Comment: Thank you for yor help, but the issue still is not resolved. I answered by editing my post.