# How can I fix 'cannot find -lR: No such file or directory' error when trying to compile a C file to DLL in Windows?

Tags: r, c, gcc

cannot find -lR: No such file or directory when import `#include <R.h>` in c.

I want to use gcc to compile a c file to dll in windows. This c file import a function `GetRNGstate()` from `#include <R.h>`.

I tried to use follow command to compile the c file:

```
gcc.exe -o test.exe test.c -I"user/R-4.2.3/include" -L"user/R-4.2.3/bin/64/" -lR
```

But I got the error: cannot find -lR: No such file or directory.

I ensure that the R.dll is in the "user/R-4.2.3/bin/64/". But I failed to deal this probelm after I tried many different command.

Comment: Does this answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128078/how-to-install-locate-r-h-and-rmath-h-header-files